# PHP File Download Using PHP Header

Tags: php, csv, header

I have a function that basically on user request gets the data from the database exports it to csv file and then automatically downloads that csv file for the user. The function works as I expected however for some reason when the file that gets downloaded to the users computer it has some random html data in it. I am not sure how this is getting added to the file as I check the file that gets created on the server and there is no random text within it. Below is the function that I am using:

```
private function _exporte() 
{
    $file_name = "/path-". date('d-m-Y') .".csv";

    if(file_exists($file_name) == TRUE) 
        unlink($file_name);

    $file = fopen($file_name, 'w') or die ("Can not open file to write");

    $file_vars = array();

    $data = $this->name_model->get_data();

    $headerDisplayed = false;

    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $file_vars['Code'] = $row['code'];
        $file_vars['Category'] = $row['category'];
        $file_vars['Category ID'] = $row['category_id'];

        if(!$headerDisplayed)
            fputcsv($file, array_keys($file_vars));

        $headerDisplayed = true;

        fputcsv($file, array_values($file_vars));
    }

    if (file_exists($file_name)) 
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_name));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));
        readfile($file_name);
    }
}
```

I have added image of the csv file for reference. [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function like bellow for download image:

```
function getLogo($path_to_your_file)
    {        
      header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
      return file_get_contents($path_to_your_file);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you time however I need all the user to download the csv file while gets created within the export function above so that they can make changes to it and can upload it back.

Comment: Doesn't work it only exports random html stuff without actual data